# CSS Media queries misbehaving when zooming in browser, but not when re-sizing the window

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, media-queries

So, I finished writing the media queries for my website to make it responsive using Chrome Dev Tools' 'Toggle device toolbar' built-in feature. Everything is working fine if I resize my browse window, but if I want to test the responsive design by zooming in, most of the css rules don't get applied.

Here are two of the media queries:

```
@media  screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    #main-text-container{
    position: absolute;
    left:10vw;
    top:20vh;
    color:white;
    width:50vw;
}

.icon{
    width:4px;
    height:4px;
}

.item-name{
    font-size:1rem;
}

#title-down{
    font-size:1.9rem;
}

#title-up{
    font-size:1.2rem;
}

#description{
    font-size:1rem;
}
}

@media  screen and (max-width: 400px) {

    #main-text-container{
    position: absolute;
    left:10vw;
    top:20vh;
    color:white;
    width:50vw;
}

.icon{
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
}

.item-name{
    font-size:0.7rem;
}

#title-down{
    font-size:1.3rem;
}

#title-up{
    font-size:0.8rem;
}

#description{
    font-size:0.8rem;
}

#map-button{
    font-size:0.8rem;
}
}
```

Here is the HTML snippet that this css block is responsible of (the website is wrote in react) :

```
<div id="main-flex-continer">
                <Navbar color={this.state.navbarColor}></Navbar>
                <div id="image-container">
                    <img id="main-image" src={backgroundImage} 
alt="bozioru"></img>
                    <div id="main-text-container">
                        <h2 id="title-up">Așezările Rupestre</h2>
                        <h1 id="title-down">Bozioru</h1>
                        <br className="sm-break"></br>
                        <p id="description">O întoarcere în peisajul 
creștinismului timpuriu,
                        unde pietrele spun povestea locului de la începutul 
istoriei și până acum.</p>
                        <button id="map-button" onClick= 
{this.redirectToMap}>Către hartă</button>
                        {this.state.redirect}
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

If I zoom, any css rule responsible for resizing the font doesn't get applied. On the other hand, the rules that resize divs are working just fine whether I zoom or I resize my browser window.

Comment: You don't really test media queries by zooming. Just resize the window

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd need to test for zooming. Responsive design is mainly to ensure the content scales on various dimensions, but that doesn't include zoom. You likely won't ever need to zoom if the content scales appropriately.

Comment: I know I don't really need zoom. Though I didn't know the rules don't apply to zooming and I thought I did something wrong because it didn't work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all should work. could you share screenshots of two page size.
most probably you already know this, but I am repeating it anyway. If you open your page in chrome, then right click / inspect in style tab you can see which rules are applied to your page as you change the size.

Comment: Thanks, your rules apply ok, your problem is with rem, it seems as you zoom in chrome change the html font which in turn changes your styling if you use px you see that your rule applies fine. Hope I could answer your question.